# Struggling to scrape multiple pages - Cheerio.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to create a web scraper using Javascript and Cheerio and I'm running into some difficulty when I try to scrape data from url's within scraped pages. For example, I scrape a first page for a few details (including a URL of a linked page) and then when I try to scrape the linked page using a callback function I am unable to assign the return value to the object. Both of the scrapers work individually however I am having issues getting them to run asynchronously and the variable detailsPage always returns as undefined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

const scrapeAllData = () => {
  return scrapeListingPage(scrapeFullDetailsPage, "www.fakeURL.com");
};



function scrapeListingPage(callbackFn, url) {
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
      let products = [];
      let singleProduct = {};

      $(".page-content-thumbs-two .row .col-sm-8").each((i, e) => {
        singleProduct = {
          price: $(e).find($("h3")),
          shortDescription: $(e).find($("p")),
          fullProductDetailsURL: $(e).find($("a")).attr("href"),
          detailsPageData: {}
        };
        singleProduct.detailsPage = scrapeFullDetailsPage(singleProduct.fullDescriptionURL);
        products.push(singleProduct);
      });
      console.log("Product DATA --> ", products);
    });
}

function scrapeFullDetailsPage(url) {
  axios.get(url).then(res => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
    let detailsPageData = {};
    $("#container").each((i, e) => {
      detailsPageData.fullDescription = $(e)
        .find($("p span"))
        .text();
    });
    console.log("detailsPageData", detailsPageData);
    return detailsPageData;
  });
}

scrapeAllData();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your `singleProduct.detailsPage` is always empty is that `scrapeFullDetailsPage()` function is asynchronous by nature, because axios library is Promise-based.

Please look into [How to make axios synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347778/how-to-make-axios-synchronous) as one potential solution, and I hope it helps.

Comment: Right but if they just move the console.log to the end of scrapeFullDetailsPage that should be fine.